# Replaceing an Image after Asynctask

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, imageview

First of all, I am a noob to Android development. So kindly explain any mistakes made.

In my App, I hav a fragment to display some images. Another class implementing an Application, does an AsyncTask to get an XML file from the web and then get the urls to the images for the imageviews in the fragment. Since it takes time time, I set the imageviews to display a loading image intially. Now when the AsyncTask completes, I want to replace these imageviews with the images from the xml, on OnPostExecute().

[I will be using loopj's SmartImageView or Android UniversalImageLoader libraries so download the image is not the problem i am facing]

I dont know how to refer the variable in that fragment from this Application class or from another seperate class in onPostExecute(). Please help me out here.

EDIT: is using a LocalBroadcastReceiver a way? is it the only way? I cant access directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a constructor for your AsyncTask and pass it your imageview.

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ImageView image;

    private MyTask(ImageView image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
```

and call it

```
MyTask task = new MyTask(imageView);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But as I mentioned my AsyncTask is in the Application class. and the imageview is in a fragment. and I dont know when the asynctask completes, from the fragment. So I cant call it from the fragment!

Comment: If you can get your activity you can use findFragmentByTag and find your fragment that way. you can create an onMyTaskFinished interface and call back to onMyTaskFinished.onFinished() in the onPostExecute() of your MyTask.

Comment: How can i get my activity on my application class? I tried passing "this" as a parameter. but then i try to call a function as mainActivity.onTaskFinished(), its not working. what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: your going to need to provide a lot more example code before i can answer that.